# Add milliseconds to a C date

Tags: c, milliseconds, strptime

I have parsed a date in C with strptime.

Now I have something like this:

```
debugLog(DEB_INFO, "observationDateConverted: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", 
                        result.tm_year+1900, 
                        result.tm_mon + 1, 
                        result.tm_mday, 
                        result.tm_hour, 
                        result.tm_min, 
                        result.tm_sec);
```

With the latest date received in result (struct tm)

I have a bunch of milliseconds like this: 1396682344000 Which I want to add to that date to know the ending date.

How should I proceed?

Comment: General approach: Turn the `struct tm` into a timestamp (64bit int) and then add `millis/1000`

Comment: How do I do that? turn into a timestamp I mean

Comment: as the milliseconds do not contain any milliseconds (`000` at the end), but only seconds you could just proceed and calculate the years/months/days/etc and add them.

Comment: But I guess that if I try to add all seconds to tm_sec, it will give me a big value and not the real seconds updating minutes and hours, will it?

Comment: A bunch of milliseconds by itself is not too useful, you need to know which moment it was measured from.

Comment: I have the start date in the result struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General approach: Turn the struct tm into a timestamp (64bit int) and then add millis/1000.

```
time_t totalseconds = mktime(&result) + (millis / 1000);
```

You can then use the functions from [C's time API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions) to convert the time stamp back to `struct tm` .

Comment: I am almost new in C. Which functions are you talking about? To search some examples or so

Comment: This page lists all functions with examples: http://fresh2refresh.com/c/c-time-related-functions/

Comment: I got the correct function and now I can get the expirationDate as a date also. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
time_t totalseconds = mktime(&result);
uint_64 endtime = (totalseconds * 1000) + msDiff;
```

Or if you want the structure back:

```
time_t totalseconds = mktime(&result),
    endtimesec = totalseconds + msDiff;
struct tm * endTime = gmtime(&endtimesec);
```

Comment: which kind of variables are totalseconds, endtime and msDiff? I have to declare them.

Comment: Note: That gives you the end time in milliseconds. You probably just want a new timestamp, so you may want to divide `msDiff` by 1000 instead to get seconds (which you can then use to convert that into a date).